# Laravel middleware get route post data and custom route key-value pairs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route that i am using to post data to server. I want to get the posted data and log that in the db. Can i get the form post data in the handle function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
      echo "...intercept post data";
      return $next($request);
   }
```

Second, i have this route for instance,

```
Route::get('role',[
   'middleware' => 'Role:editor',
   'uses' => 'TestController@index',
]);
```

I want to add a custom key value that i can access from the middleware, i.e

```
Route::get('role',[
   'middleware' => 'Role:editor',
   'uses' => 'TestController@index',
   'deed' => 'Viewed registered users'
]);
```

In the above route i added the key `deed`.Is this possible in laravel 5 and
can i access it in a middleware?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get your Route parameter from Middleware.

In your middleware you can get "matched route object" like this :

```
class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $matchedRouteObject = $request->route();
        $next($request);
    }
}
```

See `print_r($request->route())` there is a property that named `action` in this Route object. `action` property has all parameters of matched Route.

Suppose you have a middleware that named "MyMiddleware" and a controller that named "MyController"

routes/web.php :

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'MyController@index',
    'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\MyMiddleware',
    'deed' => 'View registered users'
]);
```

app/Http/Middleware/MyMiddleware.php :

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class MyMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $matchedRouteObject = $this->route();
        $deedVariable = $mathedRouteObject->action['deed']; // here you got your variable.
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no you can't do that it won't work. Use middleware only and pass an parameter like you do with `Role:editor` where `editor` is an parameter

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $editor)
```

you can also access the route infomation name, method type, from the `$request` parameter in middleware.

Remember that one query will be fired for every request from every route that uses that middleware that might not be the best approach for production. Try to fire an Event from the middleware and let the event listener handle the rest (insert query , etc).